Antitheft system enabled/car won’t start
I’m at the end of my ropes with this issue. I have a 2010 Saturn outlook xe FWD. The anti-theft system out of nowhere became enabled preventing the car from starting. I’m using the same keys and remotes that I’ve always used and the remote works fine with locking and unlocking the doors. I went to the store to buy something and when I came out and tried to start my vehicle, it would slowly crank but won’t start, I tried jumping with no success. It eventually stopped cranking altogether and I can’t even hear a click when trying to start it. I replaced the starter thinking that might fix the problem, since the fuses were ok. However, this still didn’t fix it, still no crank no start. I then noticed the security lock symbol on the dash board(not sure if it was there before I changed the starter and when the problem initially happened!!) I tried the re-learn process(10 minute re-learn 3 times and more) but that did not work either. I then took off the ignition starter switch and replaced it with a new one!! Still no luck. I called a mobile lock smith thinking that the chip inside the key might have gone bad and became unrecognizable by the immobilizer. They said everything tested ok and couldn’t figure it out either. Battery tested good at AutoZone. All radio and lights turn on fine when the key is in the ignition.
What else could I check/ replace? I don’t want to continue throwing parts at the problem without success!! Any help would be appreciated! Thank you very much!!

This may help; https://www.saturnoutlookforum.net/threads/programing-key-fob.803/

Thanks for the info. My remote controls, however, are working fine. They lock and unlock the doors with no problems. It is starting the vehicle with the key that does not work with the security lock enabled!

GM has several antitheft systems, starting with Passlock, PassKey and now, more sophistication of remotes. They may share disabling of' starter, injectors, or fuel pump with electronics easily modified for factory antitheft systems. With GMs security lock flashing, the factory antitheft system is enabled, preventing starting up. GM reset procedures are different for each system and must be performed to reset/deactivate antitheft. I know with Passlock, replacing  the Passlock sensor on the steering column must be learned. Passkey sensors may be similar. Check the Saturn Outlook forums for help.

I bought an xtool d7 scanner and it is pulling a code B1380-06 which is related to the Body Control Module. There are a lot of wires and I don’t know where to start to check for short to ground. Any suggestions. The wires I can get to look good with no wear and tear on them. Thank you!!

If B1380-06 is a Saturn Vue error code (and not xtool d7 code), this may be xtool indicating the ignition switch is ON; https://www.dtcdecode.com/Saturn/B1380-06.  I'm not familiar with xtool. However, I do recommend using Saturn service manuals; cd, online free manuals or subscription to Alldata.diy or Mitchell data.  Accurate info is needed to troubleshoot a security issue, if its disabling part of the EFI system, identifying  system parts, and wiring diagrams.  A "short to ground" may have two meanings; short circuit fault or switched ground as a signal. Correlate xtool with service manual info.

Yes it is the code I get when hooking up the xtool to the OBD port on my Saturn Outlook.

If GMs security indicator is on, blinking or flashing, each mode means something. If security is off when the ignition switch is turned ON, starting is either a fuel or spark issue. There may be a third issue. Determine if this is a security issue first, preventing starting, or not. GM antitheft systems may disable injector operation and/or fuel pump to prevent the engine from starting up.  Most factory antitheft systems disable fuel, injectors, spark or starter operation. Either find a Saturn Vue forum or have service manuals. Better repair shops or mobile techs can diagnose these problems.

The security light is solid and there is no crank at all. Not even a click when I try to start the vehicle. The security light stays lit at all times(no flashing or blinking) Thanks for the input!!

And this is leading me to believe that it is a security issue! Unless I’m missing something in my analysis!

You're describing at least two separate issues; security is bypassed from internal fault (ON), should not interfere with starting, and possibly main power connections/battery. Battery cables must be free of corrosion at battery and two main grounds (battery to chassis and chassis to engine block). Examine main power connections. Powdery blue/white deposits on battery posts; dried battery acid that will eat copper wires underneath thick insulation. Warm water solution of baking soda dissolves and neutralizes acid, water rinse.

Engine may be flooded; hold throttle pedal to floor while starting as this shuts off injectors (clear flood mode) or remove spark plugs and try cranking to blow out excess fuel, dry plugs and put them back in for another start.

Well $600 later, one of the mechanics figured it out. He said that the connection wires to the transmission was not connected properly due to dirt or something. The car starts fine and drives good. The traction control light, abs light and brake lights are on now at the same time. He thinks one or more of the abs sensors are bad, although these lights were not on before!!!? The fact that the security light was on remains a mystery as it is off now when I start the car!!! When I took the car to the Chevy dealer before, they told me the engine was locked up and that I needed an engine! Amazing!!

Any input for those lights that came on all of a sudden is greatly appreciated!

An expensive but necessary task to have someone put their hands on and use their skills  in finding elusive wiring issues. There are unscrupulous dealers among similar repair shops all preying on anyone unfamiliar with vehicle electronics. Traction control is part of the abs. A good reader (Autozone?) should be able to decode abs errors. The majority of abs errors may be wiring between abs unit module, wheel speed sensor or damage/cracked wheel reluctor, the toothed wheel each sensor detects to generate signals from years of corrosion. ABS modules rarely fail.

Thank you!! I’ll get that checked out and post an update later…And thanks again for your help throughout this thread and for your input into this issue!!
